# CrossEntropyLoss loss function type problem

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, loss-function, cross-entropy

I am trying to solve a classification problem but something is not working for me in the code.
I have a network that receives 30 inputs and outputs 4 actions.
Each action can receive an integer value from 0 to 4 (that is, receive a number between 0 and 4, a total of 5 options \ 5 classes)

I tried to implement this code but something is not working properly. I'm sure I have a problem with the dimensions
Would appreciate help !! :)

This is my code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Load data from CSV file
file_path = '/content/30_1_output.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

# Extract features and target outputs
X = df.iloc[:, :-4].values  # Assuming the last 4 columns are the target outputs
Y = df.iloc[:, -4:].values   # Extracting the last 4 columns as target outputs

# Map the values according to the specified mapping
Y = np.where(Y == -2, 0,  # If value is -2, map it to 1
            np.where(Y == -1, 1,  # If value is -1, map it to 2
                np.where(Y == 0, 2,  # If value is 0, map it to 3
                    np.where(Y == 1, 3,  # If value is 1, map it to 4
                        np.where(Y == 2, 4, Y)  # If value is 2, map it to 5
                    )
                )
            )
        )

# Split the dataset into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Convert to PyTorch tensors
X_train_tensor = torch.tensor(X_train, dtype=torch.float32)
y_train_tensor = torch.tensor(y_train, dtype=torch.long)
X_test_tensor = torch.tensor(X_test, dtype=torch.float32)
y_test_tensor = torch.tensor(y_test, dtype=torch.long)

# Create datasets and dataloaders
train_dataset = TensorDataset(X_train_tensor, y_train_tensor)
test_dataset = TensorDataset(X_test_tensor, y_test_tensor)

# Adjust the batch sizes in DataLoader to match the batch size of the model outputs
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=False)

# Define the neural network model
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, num_actions):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(input_size, 64*2)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(64*2, 32*2)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(32*2, num_actions * 5)  # 5 probabilities for each action

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer1(x)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.output_layer(out)
        out = torch.softmax(out.view(-1, 5), dim=1)  # Reshape output and apply softmax

        return out

# Initialize the model
input_size = X.shape[1]  # Number of input features
num_actions = Y.shape[1] # Number of actions
model = NeuralNetwork(input_size, num_actions)

# Define the loss function and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Training loop
num_epochs = 30
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    total_loss = 0
    for inputs, labels in train_loader:
        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(inputs)

        # Reshape outputs back to [batch_size, num_actions, 5]
        outputs = outputs.view(-1, num_actions, 5)
        # Take argmax along the last dimension to get the index of the class with the highest probability
        #outputs2 = torch.argmax(outputs, dim=2)
        #labels = labels.view(-1)

        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

        # Backward pass and optimization
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        total_loss += loss.item()

    print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {total_loss / len(train_loader):.4f}')

print("Training complete")
```

and this is the shape of the output and the labels:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axrbc.png)

Thank you so much!!

this is the error I get:

```
RuntimeError: Expected target size [64, 5], got [64, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

The label data `Y` is 4 columns:

> `Y = df.iloc[:, -4:].values   # Extracting the last 4 columns as target outputs`

whereas the model is outputting 5 columns:

> `out = torch.softmax(out.view(-1, 5), dim=1)  # Reshape output and apply softmax`

There needs to be a matching number of columns between `Y` and the model's prediction, otherwise they can't be directly compared and the loss can't be computed.

Either drop the redundant column from the model to make it exactly align with `Y`, or add the required column to `Y` to match model's output. The columns need to match in size *and meaning*, so you need to establish what the missing column represents, and where it should go.

If the data has 5 classes, and a sample can only be one of those at a time, then you can discard a class and represent the data using 4 classes (when all 4 classes are zero, it implies the 5th class). Alternatively, if you have 4 classes to begin with for a 5-class problem, you can append an extra/redundant column that explicitly flags the 5th class.